# Can I bind a RoutedCommand to a Command in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, routed-commands

I have a ViewModel of the form:

```
class VM : DependencyObject
{
    // This class exposes a command to data binding to delete things from the model
    public static DependencyProperty DeleteProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(/*...*/);

    public static ICommand Delete {
        get {
            return (ICommand)this.GetValue(DeleteProperty);
        }
        set {
            this.SetValue(DeleteProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

For a `ListBoxItem` I would like to data bind execution of `ApplicationCommands.Delete` to this `ICommand` exposed by this ViewModel. That way, when someone presses the menu item that raises `ApplicationCommands.Delete`, this particular delete will be chosen if focus is currently on this thing:

```xml
<!-- Elsewhere... -->
<MenuItem Text="Delete" Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" />

<!-- Some data template with DataContext == the above DependencyObject -->
<Grid>
    <Grid.CommandBindings>
        <!--
        I want ApplicationCommands.Delete to forward to the command {Binding Delete}
        -->
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" 
                        ???
                        />
    </Grid.CommandBindings>
</Grid>
```

... but CommandBinding can only bind to event handlers; not other commands, so I can't use MVVM-style data binding to attach it. Is there some MVVM mechanism I can use here or am I forced into adding code-behind for the `CommandBinding`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [this](https://codingcontext.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/commandbindings-in-mvvm/) tutorial to bind ApplicationCommands.
1.Add command binding collection property in your view model:

```
public CommandBindingCollection CommandBindings { get; }

public YourViewModel()
{
//Create a command binding for the delete command
var deleteBinding = new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Delete, DeleteExecuted, DeleteCanExecute);

//Register the binding to the class
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(YourViewModel), DeleteBinding);

//Adds the binding to the CommandBindingCollection
CommandBindings.Add(deleteBinding);
}
```

2. Create attached property as mentioned in the tutorial.
3. Then bind attached property in your UI.

Comment: Ah, so you mean data bind to a CommandBindingCollection instead of a command? Clever. I don't like that this makes me specify which routed command in the ViewModel (rather than XAML) but its better than what I've got now :)